# Is Bluetooth prone to data errors?

Tags: bluetooth, barcode-scanner

Our company has a brand new Bluetooth barcode scanner.  I've received reports that occasionally a wrong character is received; this is using Code 128, which has a checksum built in that should nearly eliminate misreads.

So my question is, is this something you just have to live with if you're using Bluetooth technology, or is there a problem with my specific device?

Answer (score 2):

Chances are this is not a problem with your specific device.  These devices use the 2.5 ghz unlicensed band which places it in contention for "airtime" with other devices which use the same frequencies.  It is likely that your error is related to some interference.  If you have the ability to change the frequencies of any nearby devices, this may help improve your success rate with the bluetooth scanner.

Answer (score 2):

Bluetooth implements three types of error correction.  See for example [this article](http://www.wirelessdevnet.com/channels/bluetooth/features/bluetooth.html) which covers this in the 'Link Module' section.  Given that Code 128 also provides a check digit, I suspect a problem with your specific device.  I suppose it is possible that the error is with the bluetooth communication but given the multiple levels of error detection and correction, I find this extremely unlikely.